# Tailwind 3 color palette not showing new colors

Tags: laravel-8, tailwind-css

I have upgraded to Tailwind 3 and am using Laravel 8. My tailwindconfig.js is below. When I try to use one of the newer colors (e.g., slate), it is black. I compiled with Laravel Mix, which has not reported any errors.

```
const defaultTheme = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme");
const colors = require("tailwindcss/colors");

module.exports = {
    content: [
        "./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php",
        "./storage/framework/views/*.php",
        "./resources/views/**/*.blade.php",
        "./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php",
    ],

    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ["Nunito", ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
            colors: {
                green: colors.emerald,
                yellow: colors.amber,
                purple: colors.violet,
            },
        },
    },

    plugins: [
        require("@tailwindcss/forms"),
        require("@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio"),
        require("@tailwindcss/typography"),
    ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you run `npm run dev` to push the new generated assets to the public folder?

Comment: Yes. I am running npm run dev and then that automatically calls Laravel Mix which compiles without errors.

Comment: Looking through the app.css which mix makes I can see that it has a heading of "tailwindcss v3.0.18 | MIT License | https://tailwindcss.com" but despite requiring tailwindcss/colors they do not appear to be defined in the app.css

Comment: In vendor/tailwindcss/src/public/colors.js the new colours are defined.

Comment: @Jim Browserache?

Comment: No. Jim Elliott

Comment: @Jim :-) I mean if you sure that the old css is not cached in the browsercache? Checked maybe with an other browser, too.

Comment: Sorry I read Browserache as a name! I have tried clearing the cache and using another browser.

Answer (score 0):

You've placed the colors at the wrong position in your code:

```
theme: {

    colors: {
        transparent: 'transparent',
        current: 'currentColor',
        green: colors.emerald,
        yellow: colors.amber,
        purple: colors.violet,
    },

    extend: {
        fontFamily: {
            sans: ["Nunito", ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
        },
    },
},
```